# Split a string into multiple X strings without losing any data

Tags: c, string, split

I'm trying to create a method that splits a string into X strings. Now the problem with the method that I've created is that if the input string is not a perfect division, the string gets cut off and I lost a fragment of the original string. Can you help me fix it?

```
#define PARTSTRINGLEN 8;

void splitString(const char *text){
    const char **partString;
    int n = PARTSTRINGLEN;
    int i;
    size_t len = strlen(text);

    partString = malloc(sizeof(*partString) * len / n);

    for (i = 0; i < (len / n); i++)
    {
        partString[i] = strndup(text + n * i, (size_t) n);
        printf("%s\n", partString[i]);
    }
}
```

For example: `char text[] = "this is a string used as an example"`
The result is:

```
this is ,
a string,
 used as,
 an exam.
```

Instead the actual result that i seek is:

```
this is ,
a string,
 used as,
 an exam,
ple.
```

Comment: You want your splits by which criteria?

Comment: `sizeof(*partString) * ceil((float)len / n)` (Updated - typo)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop has to be longer by 1 if you have leftover fragment which is less then `PARTSTRINGLEN`. Proper memory allocation and freeing have to be dealt with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PARTSTRINGLEN 8

char ** splitString(const char *text, size_t len1){
    char **partString;
    int n = PARTSTRINGLEN;
    size_t i;

    partString = (char **) malloc( sizeof(*partString) * len1);

    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        partString[i] = strndup(text + n * i, (size_t) n);

        printf("%s\n", partString[i]);
    }

    return partString;
}

int main (void)
{
  char ** ptr;
  char *str = "this is a string used as an example";   
  size_t len = strlen(str); 

  size_t len1 = len/PARTSTRINGLEN;
  if(len%PARTSTRINGLEN) len1++;

  ptr = splitString(str,len1);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len1; i++)
     free(ptr[i]);

  free(ptr);

  return 0; 
}
```

Result:

```
  this is                                                                                                                            
a string                                                                                                                           
 used as                                                                                                                           
 an exam                                                                                                                           
ple
```

Comment: that's exacly it! 
By "take care of the memory" you mean that i should add free(partString) in the end? Even if i need to use those partString somewhere else?

Comment: @Fabzheimer Keep the allocated strings as long as you need them. Release at the end of the program. Suggestion: `return partString;`  from `splitString` so you can have a handle to the allocated memory!

Comment: Yes, infact i was going to :) Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to use `len1` in the `malloc`.

Comment: @sg7 Should you not be using `len1` for the `malloc` instead of `len / n`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, the memory allocation has to take care of the  remaining ` len%n`!

Comment: @Fabzheimer I have update the program with the allocation and the cleanup.